# Find percentage overlap (by category) between census tract polygons and circular polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-processing

## Context

This is my second attempt to post this question since the answers to my first question were not as useful as I had hoped. The link to my first question is here: [first question attempt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241545/how-do-i-find-the-overlapping-area-between-polygons-on-2-vector-layers-in-qgis/)

I am trying to solve a problem at a national level but am starting with Rhode Island to solidify my approach. Thus, everything in this question will be focused on the state of Rhode Island.

Here is the map I am starting out with:
[image: Starting Map]
The polygons are census tracts and the points are company office locations.

**I’d like to figure out the following:** For each census tract in Rhode Island, what percent of land area is covered by a certain company (total of 3 companies). Making sure that water area is not included in the calculations.

And just as an FYI, I am extremely new to GIS in general and have been going at this problem for a few days now. I am using QGIS 2.18.9.

## Inputs

I have 3 input files:

1. The 2010 Census Tract shapefile (RI_Tracts) for Rhode Island with edited fields for simplicity:[image: RI_Tracts]
2. A CSV file (RI_Tract_Tiers) that classifies each census tract into tiers 1-5:[image: RI_Tract_Tiers]
3. A CSV file (RI_Offices) for office locations with the following fields:[image: RI_Offices]

## Desired Output

A table that looks something like this:[image: Desired_Output]

## What I've Tried

1. Join the RI_Tracts table with the RI_Tract_Tiers table to classify the Tracts into tiers
2. Color code the census tracts by Tract_Tier
3. Import and buffer the company locations in the RI_Offices file

   - Buffer distance is 10,000ft (3048 meters), so I enter “0.030480” into the distance field of the Fixed Distance Buffer tool
4. Dissolve the company locations by Office_Category to get rid of any overlaps b/w the same company
5. Color code the company locations by Office_Category

Here is the map I end up with after performing the steps above:[image: ending_map]

**This is where I get stuck.** I have tried using the following tools to analyze the map and get the output I want (with no success):

- Union
- Intersect
- Statistics by Categories

Comment: You can use the Clip Tool with [input layer: tracts] and [ clip layer: your dissolved buffer]. That will produce new tract_id based polygons.